# How to find a key with a specific value in an object in an array, and then swap that key with that value?

Tags: javascript, maps

My goal is to write a script that goes though an array of objects. It needs to find the keys with the value "age," so that "age" become the key, and the numbers become the values. It then needs to be reformated. The reformating works just fine, but I can't change the tags without a for loop, which is not what the assignment asks.

My current code looks like this:

```
function mapCharacters(comiccharacters) {



const supers = comiccharacters.map(({ name, isHero, age}) => {

    for (let i = 0; i < comiccharacters.length; i++) 
    {

        for (var key in comiccharacters[i]) 
     {
         if (comiccharacters[i][key] === 'age') 
         {
             [key, comiccharacters[i][key]] = [comiccharacters[i][key], key]

         }

     }

     }
  


    if (isHero == true) {

        console.log(age);
        return "hero: " + name + ", age: " + age;

    }

    else {

        return "villain: " + name + ", age: " + age;

    }
});


console.log(supers);
```

}

```
mapCharacters([
    { name: 'Spider-Man', isHero: true, '28': 'age' },
    { name: 'Thor', isHero: true, '1500': 'age' },
    { name: 'Black Panther', isHero: true, '35': 'age' },
    { name: 'Loki', isHero: false, '1054': 'age' },
    { name: 'Venom', isHero: false, 'unknown': 'age' }
])
```

However, what I did with the for loop, I need to do with map functions. I would like advice as to how

Answer (score 0):

First you have to loop throught the array. Then for each object key, check if the value is `age`. When found, delete the property from the object and set a new one with the key `age` and the value `key`.

```js
let mapCharacters = [
  { name: "Spider-Man", isHero: true, 28: "age" },
  { name: "Thor", isHero: true, 1500: "age" },
  { name: "Black Panther", isHero: true, 35: "age" },
  { name: "Loki", isHero: false, 1054: "age" },
  { name: "Venom", isHero: false, unknown: "age" }
];

let reorganized = mapCharacters.map(item => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach(key => {
    if (item[key] == "age") {
      delete item[key]
      item = { ...item, age: key }
    }
  })
  return item
})

console.log(reorganized)
```